# Função definida não definida

Tags: javascript, html5, funções

Minha função que esta sendo chamada durante o evento onclick não está sendo reconhecida, este é o erro do console:

```
ReferenceError: abrirfoto is not defined
```

HTML(apenas código relevante):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Mycode</title>
        <script src="Javascript/javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
    <div id="layout">
       <main>
            <section>
                <ul id="dpf">
                    <li onclick="abrirfoto(this);"><img src="Backgrounds/Foto1.jpg"></li>
                    <li onclick="abrirfoto(this);"><img src="Backgrounds/Foto2.jpg"></li>
                    <li onclick="abrirfoto(this);"><img src="Backgrounds/Foto3.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </main> 
    </div>
</body>
```

obs:no codigo inteiro o atributo "alt" é utilizado nas imagens.

Javascript

```
function abrirfoto(myElement) {
    myElement.style.width = 300px;
}
```

Tentei colocar a minha função dentro de uma tag script do meu html5,mas o mesmo erro persiste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duas coisas a corrigir:

- `#1` - colocar a função no escopo global
- `#2` - passar uma referência ao elemento clicado á função

### #1 - escopo

O erro `ReferenceError: abrirfoto is not defined` acontece quando a função não está acessível globalmente. Um exemplo disso é:

```
window.onload = function(){
    function abrirfoto() {
        this.style.width = 300px;
    }
}
```

Neste exemplo a função é defenida dentro de outra função e por isso só acessível dentro dela.

Solução:

```
function abrirfoto() {
    this.style.width = 300px;
}
window.onload = function(){
    // e aqui o código que realmente precisa de estar aqui
}
```

### #2 - contexto

O segundo problema é que na função estás a chamar o `this` que não é o que pensas. Quando usas uma abordagem onde fazes `li.addEventListener(...` aí sim o contexto de execução (ou seja o que o `this` aponta) é o elemento. Quando usas inline no HTML o `this` é o `window`.

Solução:

HTML:

```
<li onclick="abrirfoto(this)"><img src="Backgrounds/Foto1.jpg"></li>
```

JavaScript:

```
function abrirfoto(el) {
    el.style.width = 300px;
}
```

#### Há maneiras melhores para fazer isto?

Sim, como o [Brumazzi DB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/134645/129) também referiu, podes fazer isso com CSS. Nesse caso talvez somente isto [faça o que queres](https://jsfiddle.net/j14w6kkv/):

```
li:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Se não fôr sufeciente usa classes de CSS e muda a classe no elemento assim por exemplo:

```
function abrirfoto(el) {
    el.classlist.add('red');
}
```

e no CSS:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente quando se coloca `this` dentro de um método em *JavaScript*, o interpretador insere um atributo dentro do método.

Para modificar o tamanho como quer, deve passar o objeto como parâmetro para dentro do seu método.

```js
function call(element){
  element.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="call(this);">a</li>
  <li onclick="call(this);">b</li>
  <li onclick="call(this);">c</li>
  <li onclick="call(this);">d</li>
  <li onclick="call(this);">e</li>
</ul>
```

Para usar o `this` dentro do método, tem de se atribuir um método diretamente para o atributo desejado do seu objeto, tento que capturá-lo por `id`, `class`, etc. Assim o `this` dentro do método passa a ser exclusivo do seu elemento.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('d');

el.onclick = function(){
  this.style.background= 'red';
}
```

```html
<div id="d">
  asdad
</div>
```

> De preferencia pelo *CSS* para qualquer tipo de alteração na parte visual de seu código.

Comment: Na verdade isso é exatamente oque eu tinha feito antes,mas parece que quando uso o "onlclick" para uma função o "this" dentro da função ja se refere ao elemento que chamou a função.Não lembro onde tinha lido isso(ou até mesmo se me confundi)mas pode confirmar pra mim?E aquele ponto e virgula no final do "onlclick" é necessario?

Comment: Acrescentei uma explicação referente a sua duvida de usar o `this`, e quanto ao `;`, é necessário caso queira chamar mais de um método dentro do `onclick` no *HTML*

Comment: Obrigado amigo! :D